# Excel Application return "File Save" instead of "Save As" dialog

Tags: c#, excel, com, ms-office

Why `auto dialog = _excelApp.get_FileDialog(Office.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogSaveAs);`
returns "File Save" dialog?

[image]

How to get "Save As" dialog?

Comment: Was the file ever saved before?

Comment: yes. I open an existing file

Comment: There is only one dialog that helps getting the name of the file to save.  Its name in the title bar is not relevant and beyond your control.

Comment: @HansPassant I dont want to get the name of the file to save. What I am saying is that get_FileDialog return a wrong dialog. I want to display "Save As" dialog, but it return "File Save" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Save as" dialog in Excel at all. I can see only a "File save" dialog.

Even using the UI in any possible situation I can only see only one "File save" dialog that is used to ask for a name the first time, or ask for a new name.

So using msoFileDialogSaveAs is all you have.

Comment: What version of Excel do you use?

Comment: mine is Excel 2016 and it does have Save As dialog

Comment: @RandomUser Can you please add a screenshot from your special SaveAs dialog as you did for Save dialog?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in microsoft's dll. I used another interface which works fine:

```
Excel.Dialog dialog = _excelApp.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSaveAs];
dialog.Show();
```